# Raster formats that support colormaps for floating-point data in GDAL?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, floating-point

I am writing a program to overlay a raster image over a map in a KDE Marble project.  I am using a combination of QGIS and GDAL to convert non-standard NetCDF data to a raster file.  I began using GeoTIFF as there is wide support for reading and writing in the format; however, the data cannot be assigned a colormap because it is floating point.  Any way around this?  I tried one workaround which was to do:

```
gdaldem color-relief myfile.tif mycolorfile.clr output.tif
```

but the metadata returned all zeros for each colorband.

Comment: Colormaps exist to map discrete integer values to specific RGB values, as a form of compression. Floating-point values and colormaps are not compatible. Perhaps you mean something to do with symbology...

Comment: @Vince perhaps yes.  I am fairly new to gis software.